# US Citizenship through Birth

Tags: immigration, citizenship, us-citizens

I am a lawful legal immigrant and my daughter was born here(USA).

I have below questions.

1) Whats are all the benefits she will get for born in the United States compared to a person citizenship through naturalization?

2) What are all the investment that I can made in her name right now in the United Sates apart from 529C ?(she is 3 months old)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The only additional benefit accorded to a natural-born citizen of the US is the right to become president or vice president.  In addition, naturalized citizens may be denaturalized if it transpires that their application for naturalization was fraudulent.  Natural-born citizens of the US do not need to worry about that.
2. In general, you can make any investment in her name, but you will want to talk to a financial planner to minimize the tax impact.

Comment: Thanks for your comments